# Audio streaming bandwith

Tags: networking, audio, streaming, bandwidth, audio-streaming

I am trying to understand the bandwidth consumed by hosting a Audio Streaming server and Web Site that will host the stream.

> Server A: will host the IceCast server & Media
>
> Server B: will host a Web-Site that will act as the front end playing
> the stream.

Will **Server A** consume the same amount of bandwidth for each person listening to the web-site. As **Server B** will consume for each one connecting to feed off the IceCast server?

Comment: So all the media you are hosting will be on Server A but be accessible through Server B. While people can connect directly to Server A with a player?

Comment: yes people will be listening on serve bwww.professionalroofingdbq.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup **Server A** will consume the most bandwidth due to the icecast server, taking into account you have more people listening with the player. 
**Server B** will not consume any bandwidth of those connected directly to **Server A's** icecast server.

Now if you have most of your listeners or viewers using the web front end on **Server B** then **Server B** will use almost the same bandwidth as **Server A**. 

* **Server B** should not use more bandwidth than **Server A**, unless all traffic to and from **Server A** is from the web front end. In this case **Server B** will use more bandwidth but it will be marginally more. This extra bandwidth will be from making connections and loading the front end to the listener. 
Because the bandwidth required for each audio stream will always be the same, the only difference would be how its presented to the listeners. The web front end would have some extra overhead that the IceCast server wouldn't have. So doing a strict comparison of "listening" bandwidth between the 2 servers would show **Server B** using slightly more bandwidth.

Comment: Will the web-site use as much bandwidth for each "listener" as Server A would use for each "listener" connecting directly to Server A?

Comment: Updated answer to show that comparing the listening streams would show server b using slightly more. This is from the overhead of the web front end.